# Expanding a text with backspace at the end

Tags: text, autohotkey, symbols, expansion, backspace

I am new to autohotkey and I'm trying to expand a text but I need to add a "backspace" at the end of the sentence,
for example:

```
::btw::by the way
return
```

works fine, except that when I get the expansion, I get a space at the end,

if I do this

```
::sq::start quote"
return
```

I would like to be able to type right after the **"**(quote) symbol, (instead i get (start quote " text") {check the space before " text")
My expectation = ( start quote "text" )

I want to do something like this:

```
::sq::start quote"{bs}
return
```

but Im not getting the result I need.

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put an `O` in the options between the first two colons:

```
:O:sq::start quote"
```

From the help:

> **O**: Omit the ending character of auto-replace hotstrings when the
>   replacement is produced. This is useful when you want a hotstring to
>   be kept unambiguous by still requiring an ending character, but don't
>   actually want the ending character to be shown on the screen. For
>   example, if :o:ar::aristocrat is a hotstring, typing "ar" followed by
>   the spacebar will produce "aristocrat" with no trailing space, which
>   allows you to make the word plural or possessive without having to
>   backspace. Use O0 (the letter O followed by a zero) to turn this
>   option back off.
>
> http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm